# Where is it documented that a string subscript produces a character?

Tags: javascript

I was surprised when I did this:

```
var s = "Cities of the Internet";
var strings = s.split(" ");
alert (s[2]); // shows t!!!!!
```

Of course I realized that I meant strings[2], but why does subscripting a string produce a character.  Did I miss something in my reading of JavaScript books?  I probably did.  Is this standard?

Comment: Ending your question like that won't gain you any good will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Character_access

Comment: This source states (as Jonathan pointed out, thanks) that this is not part of ECMAScript 3. It is a JavaScript and ECMAScript 5 feature.  I think that this is helpful to know, and as been pointed out, many JavaScript implementations had been doing it like this prior to 5.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting a canonical reference, you should be looking for the ECMA-262 spec. There's a [HTML version](http://ecma262-5.com/) which I find quite handy.

For being able to access specific characters by index, § 15 is where I'd start. I see some relevant material there.

**[§ 15.5.5](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_Section_15.htm#Section_15.5.5) Properties of String Instances**

> The array index named properties correspond to the individual
>   characters of the String value. A special [[GetOwnProperty]] internal
>   method is used to specify the number, values, and attributes of the
>   array index named properties.

Which in turn refers to [§ 15.5.5.2](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_Section_15.htm#Section_15.5.5.2), as that is where [[GetOwnProperty]] is defined. The spec is rather dense and difficult to read, but if you are wanting some sort of canonical description of why this happens, there it is.

Answer (score 0):

Because s[2] equals to "Cities of the Internet"[2]. The right code is:

```
var s = "Cities of the Internet";
var strings = s.split(" ");
alert (strings [2]); // shows the!!!!!
```

Comment: SOrry, I forgot removing this commment

Answer (score -1):

```
var s = "Cities of the Internet";
```

As we see, `s` is a string.

```
var strings = s.split(" ");
```

Now, `strings` is an array of the strings `"Cities", "of", "the", "Internet"`, as it was created by splitting `s` over a space.

```
alert (s[2]);
```

You're alerting the third character (because they are numbered from 0) of the string `s`.

```
"Cities of the Internet"[2] == "t"
```

This is the "t" in the word "Cities". Your confusion probably arises from the fact that you wanted to call

```
alert (strings[2]);
```

And no, I will not point you to a book chapter for such a trivial matter.

Comment: Okay, now that you edited your question this response does not answer it. Anyway, I can say as much that you're not a very good reader, as subscripting a string returns a character on that position in virtually any programming language. What else would you expect, anyway?